# Getting the vertex values for a point

Tags: node-editor, vertices, geometry

I'm trying to get all vertex values from a bounding box.

For each one, I'm using this

[image]

Is this going to return the correct X/Y/Z for the vertex at position 'index'?

I'm on 3.5 and the values it's returning are slightly off what I'm expecting.

Thanks

Comment: maybe show your whole example with values so we can help you?  and would be great if you also show us the value you would expect.